# Why isn't my javascript changing my css to make my button work?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm making a navigation bar and my goal is that when you're a mobile device and you click the menu button or "nav-toggle", the whole navigation bar which is hidden at the max-width of 35em should be showing up on button click.

```js
const ulNav = document.querySelector(".ul-navbar");
const navButt = document.querySelector(".nav-toggle");
//on click visibility is checked, if its "false", the data-visible attribute in css would be set to true and if its "true" it would be set to false.
navButt.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const vis = ulNav.getAttribute('data-visible');

    console.log(vis)
    if (vis === "false") {
        ulNav.setAttribute("data-visible", true);
    } else if (vis === "true") {
        ulNav.setAttribute("data-visible", false);
    }
});
```

```css
/* p-head */
.primary-header {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
/* for mobile devices */
@media (max-width: 35em) {
  .ul-navbar {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 30%;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: min(30vh, 10rem) 2rem;

    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  /* what the javscript should be changing */
  .ul-navbar [data-visible="true"] {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  .nav-toggle {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url(amburger.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    background: red;
    top: 2rem;
    right: 2rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header class ="primary-header flex" >
        
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html">
                <img class = "img" src="./imges/beatlejuce.png" alt="logo">
            </a>
        </div>
        <button class="nav-toggle" aria-controls="ul-nav" aria-expanded="false">Menu</button>
        <nav>
<ul id="ul-nav" data-visible="false" class ="ul-navbar flex">
    <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">code</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">photography</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">random</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">login</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

What should be happening is on button click the javascript changes the css inside of the max-width media query making the data-visible="true" to "false" and back if button is to be clicked again. For some reason, nothing is changing, maybe I had some type of error in my use of data-visible, but if its not that, I dont really know how to fix this.

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow has functionality that combines HTML, CSS, and JavaScript into a single runnable snippet. [Edit] your question, copy your code and click the button that looks like `<>` on the editor toolbar. There are boxes for each language. Paste the code in the appropriate boxes and voila, runnable code.

Comment: i suggest onclick events

Comment: `.ul-navbar [data-visible="true"]` <-- saying a child has the attribute, that whitespace is your bug. `.ul-navbar[data-visible="true"]`

Comment: @epascarello Yep, that fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: @WebDevDude what do you think this is `navButt.addEventListener("click",`?

Comment: no dude, like an onclick function.   eg  <button onclick="anyfunction()" >  text 
    </button>

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to find your element like a class. Change your const ulNav to this:

```
const ulNav = document.querySelector("#ul-navbar");
```

Comment: Why not `getElementById` instead?

Comment: The class is correct: `<ul id="ul-nav" data-visible="false" class="ul-navbar flex">`

`const ulNav = document.querySelector(".ul-navbar");`  - works correct.

Comment: @MikhailSidorov It worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @JohnJAF I gave an answer above: you have an incorrect selector `.ul-navbar [data-visible=true]` fix it, and everything will work. Don't remember to check it in correct screen width (max-width: 35em)

Answer (score 0):

There is an incorrect selector here:

```
.ul-navbar [data-visible=true] {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

Should be:

```
.ul-navbar[data-visible=true] {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```